# redirect to My Website while clicking on App Invitation in facebook

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an app in Facebook. And sent requests to friends, or invite friends to My website using the Request Dialog.

Now its working as follows: receiver clicks on the request - then page redirects to the app page and the website loads as canvas URL.

How can I redirect to the website on Separate tab - when user clicks on the Facebook app request notification?